# Why won't div float next to image? (goes behind image instead)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an image, and then to the right of the image I want a div box to be there. I've been trying to search for the reason for this, but I cannot find it. I'm assuming div's can't be floated next to images for some reason because I've successfully done it with text.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8ZDQ/1/
(you can see the red div box is actually mostly behind the image, only part of it is popping out the right side)

HTML:

```
<img src="http://stignatiusyardley.org/pictures/NFP/NFP%20family%20image.jpg" style="float:left;width:370px;height:246px;" />
```

​

CSS:

```
#optin {
width:466px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
height:166px;
background-color:red;
```

}​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The div itself is not floating!  Try adding `float: left` to `#optin`.

Comment: ohhhhh...... i was thinking regularly i just float the iamge and then just let everything go next to it... lol. thanks jesse!

Answer (score 3):

The DIV is a `block` level element by default. Only `inline` or `inline-block` elements will display the way you want. To get the effect you need, you need to either make the DIV `display: inline-block` or `float: left`.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the css of #optin to float as well

```
#optin {
    width:466px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height:166px;
    background-color:red;
    float: left;
}​
```